# table doesn't work with baposter

Tags: tables, posters, baposter

I am making a poster with baposter. When I want to make a table (put in `\headerbox{}`), I got error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H <return>  for 
immediate help.
...

l.219   }

! Undefined control sequence. \caption@ORI@xfloat ... \global \setbox \@currbox
                                              \color@vbox \normalcolor \...
l.219   }

! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again>
               \vbox
l.219   }
```

If I remove `\begin{table}[ht]` and `end{table}` below, I got an array.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{equation*}  \scalemath{0.8}{
\begin{array}{ | c | c | c | c | } \hline
  dy & x & x^2 & x^3 \\ \hline
  1 & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\ \hline
  y & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\ \hline
  y^2 & \times & \times & \times \\ \hline
\end{array} }
\end{equation*}
\end{table}
```

Do I need a special trick to make a table when I use baposter class?

Here is the code. You need baposter.cls.

```
\documentclass[portrait]{baposter}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{overpic}

\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}

\newcommand{\ket}[1]{| #1 \rangle}
\newcommand{\E}{\text{e}}
\newcommand{\I}{\text{i}}
\newcommand{\Hand}{$\:$ \HandRight $\:\:$}

\usepackage[square,comma,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}
\setlength{\bibsep}{3pt}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\usepackage{palatino}

\graphicspath{{images/}}

% border around images
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand{\figureborder}{
  {
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \node[fill=white,very thick,draw=gray,rounded corners=2mm,inner
      sep=5pt] (background) [fit = (A)] {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  }
}

\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{Yellow}{RGB}{253,176,61}
\definecolor{OxfordBlue}{RGB}{0,0,102}
\definecolor{TodaiBlue}{RGB}{90,141,201}
\definecolor{LighterBlue}{RGB}{241,244,255}

\begin{poster}
  {
    grid=no,                         % show grid to help with alignment
    colspacing=0.33cm,               % column spacing
    bgColorOne=white,                % top background color (only color for background=plain)
    bgColorTwo=LighterBlue,          % bottom background color (for background=shade-tb)
    background=plain,
    borderColor=black,               % line color around the insets
    headerColorOne=TodaiBlue,        % top color of inset header gradient
    headerColorTwo=OxfordBlue,       % bottom color of inset header gradient
    headerFontColor=white,           % font color of inset header
    boxColorOne=LighterBlue,
    boxColorTwo=Yellow,
    textborder=rounded-small,        % Format of textbox
    eyecatcher=no,                   % Format of text header
    headerborder=closed,
    headerheight=0.093\textheight,   % height of the top header (use only if necessary)
    headershape=small-rounded,
    headershade=shade-tb,
    headerfont=\Large\bf,            % font type for inset header
    boxshade=plain,
    linewidth=1.2pt                  % thickness of line around the insets
  }
  {
    % No Eye Catcher.
  }
  { % Poster Title
    \sf \huge % \sf = sans serif font
    \vspace{0.7cm} % distance from the top
    \textbf{This is the title}
  }
  { % Author, Logo
    \begin{minipage}{15.0cm} % define the width of the minipage.

      % Author
      \sf
      Author$^{1}$ \\

      \vspace{-0.5cm}

      % Institute
      \scriptsize
      $^1${Institut}
      \par
    \end{minipage}

  }



  \headerbox{Box}{name=G3Curves,column=0, span=1.2}{

        This is a test.

%\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{equation*}  \scalemath{0.8}{
\begin{array}{ | c | c | c | c | } \hline
  dy & x & x^2 & x^3 \\ \hline
  1 & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\ \hline
  y & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\ \hline
  y^2 & \times & \times & \times \\ \hline
\end{array} }
\end{equation*}
%\end{table}

  }


\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't use `table` inside a box and you're trying to use it in `\headerbox`. Why should you want `table`?

Comment: You don't need a `table` environment. as you don't want it to float. Your code with that commented out is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 6):

The environment `table` is a floating object. Floating objects aren't allowed inside boxes. So simple remove the environment `table`.

The explanation is given in the questions:

- [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)
- [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are
  mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)

Comment: I guess using `\captionof` is better for posters

Comment: @percusse: it is a cw. Feel free to edit the answer.